# is there sessions in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm making a chat app in node.js with socket.io so i'm tying to store some information about each user in server side but the problem is that i have noticed that socket.io always update the previous information with new ones after each connection. to clear it more. here is what i have done.

## CLIENT SIDE:

(in client side there is a button that get client ID from server side)

```
io.on("get id", (id)=>{
    alert(id);
});

function getID(){
    io.emit("get id");
}
```

## SERVER SIDE:

```
socket.on("get id", ()=>{
    io.emit("get id", socket.id);
});
```

So now if a user clicked button it shows his ID. but if another user visited the page and clicked button socket.io will replace the previous ID with the new one so the first user will get the second user's id.
I don't want to store them in client side because of security concerns :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can modify `socket` object on backend to add any data you want

Comment: really? so how can i save each socket.id for a period of time like a session with ```socket``` object? sorry but i'm totally new to node.js and socket.io

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express you can use this module:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session